# What's the correct way to insert custom JavaScript to a post page in NextJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, hot-reload

I'm a newbie in NextJS and I'm using it to create a personal blog. As per the NextJS tutorial, static assets should be put in the **/public** top-level folder. I can load images and .css from the **/public** folder just fine into my posts but I'm having trouble inserting custom JS into my posts. To be more precise I can see that the scripts seem are being inserted into each post when I inspect the page, but they're not being executed until I manually refresh the page.

I created a custom Script component with a src prop to load custom javascript and I am using it for each of my post pages like this:

```
        <Layout>
            <Head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highlightjs/cdn-release@10.3.1/build/styles/vs.min.css" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/custom.css" type="text/css" />
            </Head>
            <div className="post-content" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.content}} />
            <Script src="/highlight.pack.js" />
            <Script src="/init.js" />
        </Layout>
```

So, in the example above, if I'm navigation through the site and click on a particular post link, the post will load but the scripts I included above will not be executed (this doesn't happen with custom CSS). If I reload the page, the scripts will run just fine; so the problem seems to be when navigating between pages.

How can I fix this?

Thanks.